# invoking do_fork with copy-on-write disabled

Tags: kernel, system-calls, copy-on-write

I am doing an Operating System assignment, which is adding a new system call. The system call, which is called "dumbfork", needs to fork a process without using copy-on-write policy. So basically it has to copy the entire address space to the child process.

I was able to set up and recompile the system kernel. I can invoke my custom system call, but I don't know how to actually implement the dumbfork to disable COW feature. One of the source code shows me how [sys_vfork](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/arch/avr32/kernel/process.c#L375) is calling do_fork. Dumbfork should be similar to sys_vfork. I don't know how I can set the parameters of do_fork. I tried to mimick how sys_fork is implemented, and it gives me a NULL pointer dereferencing error. Can anyone enlighten me on this problem.

```
asmlinkage long sys_dumbfork(struct pt_regs *regs)
{
  return do_fork(SIGCHLD, regs->sp, regs, 0, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Comment: `sys_vfork` does exactly the opposite of what you want!!

Comment: Yes, right. vfork passes flags CLONE_VM, CLONE_VFORK,and SIGCHLD to do_fork and shares the address space. Anyway a child from vfork will do exec or exit, so that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`do_fork` is a very general function which is used in `fork`, `vfork` and `clone` calls. The most similar one  to what you want to achieve is obviously `fork` (`clone` is mainly intended for threads, `vfork` does not copy address space at all).

In your case, the best solution seems to be making `do_fork` accept new flag, somthing like `CLONE_COPY_EVERYTHING_RIGHT_NOW`. Then you should find code responsible for copy-on-write and depending on whether this flag was passed to `do_fork`: copy entire adress space or (if flag was not passed, what would indicate that `do_fork` was called from one of the original system calls) use existing copy-on-write policy. Your `dumbfork` system call will look almost the same like `fork` call, except the additional flag.

```
asmlinkage int sys_dumbfork(struct pt_regs *regs)
{
     return do_fork(CLONE_COPY_EVERYTHING_RIGHT_NOW | SIGCHLD, regs->sp, regs, 0, NULL, NULL);
}
```

[This](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/KernelAnalysis-HOWTO-6.html) page, although outdated, may be very helpful, especially the sections **Fork ICA** and **Copy on Write**. There is a function called during `fork` syscall `copy_page_range` which marks pages read-only. That looks like the place you should consider for adding your memory copying code.  Moreover, function `do_wp_page` is called during page faults in order to copy previously shared page someone wanted write to, that may be a good example how such copying should look like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still don't get this in detail. Do you mean I need to modify do_fork, so the new flag can be used, and use the modified do_fork instead of the original? To use a modified do_fork, the whole fork.c should be copied for my new system call, right?

Comment: I think you should modify do_fork so it will be useful for both original system calls (without the new flag it should work in the same way as previously) and your new system call (when the flag is passed it should copy whole address space). I updated my answer in order to make it more clear.